# Download custom containers in github actions/workflows from AWS ECR

Tags: github, github-actions, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I would like to use custom containers to execute my github actions job. This is documented in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container#example-running-a-job-within-a-container
It is possible to download an image for the container from ECR if I provide "username" and "password" as the "credentials" of the container.

But I would like to use OIDC and IAM roles for that. So far I found one solution consisting of multiple jobs and passing the short-lived creds between them:

```
---
name: Manual test
"on":
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  get_creds:
    permissions:
      id-token: write # This is required for requesting the JWT
      contents: read  # This is required for actions/checkout
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    steps:
      - name: configure aws credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v3
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::123456:role/GithubWorkflow
          aws-region: us-east-1  
      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2
        with:
          mask-password: 'false'
    outputs:
      docker_username: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.docker_username_123456_dkr_ecr_us_east_1_amazonaws_com }}
      docker_password: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.docker_password_123456_dkr_ecr_us_east_1_amazonaws_com }}


  job1:
      needs: [get_creds]
      permissions:
        id-token: write # This is required for requesting the JWT
        contents: read  # This is required for actions/checkout
      runs-on: [self-hosted]
      container:
        image: 123456.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3rdparty/library/alpine:3.18.4
        credentials:
          username: ${{ needs.get_creds.outputs.docker_username }}
          password: ${{ needs.get_creds.outputs.docker_password }}
      steps:
        - name: Step1
          run: |
            cat /etc/os-release
```

(the alpine is just a debugging example)

Is there another (simpler) option?

Another solution I am thinking of is to get all the operations from aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials + aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login and put them as a prepare_job mentioned in the docs for runners: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/customizing-the-containers-used-by-jobs
But I am not sure if the runner already has the OIDC token needed to assume the correct role here and honestly I don't fully understand the typescript code in those actions to get what they do.